# How does extra time for disability apply to take home University essays, lab reports, etc. that are scheduled ahead of time?

Tags: university, health, homework

Timed exams are a large part of university courses' curriculum and grades but another part is work that is assigned to be done outside of class on the student's own time. Could be scientific lab reports, research essays, presentations, etc.

My question is how do academic insitutions address this if at all?

Does the student full/part time matter?

If the deadline is within a few days, a week, etc.?

Time of completed lab results vs time spent writing lab report?

Length of assignment?

What if it is Finals week or a week where the student has various exams scheduled within the week?

I've found little information online about it other than the 2014 ADA online testing accomodations report that states "Testing entities must ensure that the test scores of individuals with disabilities accurately reflect the individual’s aptitude or achievement level or whatever skill the exam or test is intended to measure."

Untimed assignments have a different purpose that ones that have be completed in one sitting. As there is university assignments that test your ability to find outside research digest it and input it in your work without plagarism. Procrastination may be something that needs to be considered when weeks or months of advance notice are given. However, the solution can't only be for a student to manage his own off class time when there are only so many hours in a day or a week.

Comment: This is a purely local question. It depends on what your university and country permit and expect. There is no general answer. Professors might have some leeway or not. Ask whoever is responsible for this at your own university.

Comment: An assignment is not an exam, so normally an extended time accommodation for “exams” would not apply, even if the assignment is “timed”. Your question might be relevant for things like take-home exams, but honestly I think it should be answerable by a careful reading of your accommodation letter and the take-home exam instructions. If in doubt, as @buffy said only your instructor and/or your institution’s student disability center are in a position to answer the question authoritatively.

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer as to how we deal with this sort of thing. And the answer is that in general we are guided by the indevidaul "Learning Support Plan" that is drawn up in consulation between the student and worker assigned to the student by our Disablity and Dyslexia Support Service.

I've seen all possible combinations - Students should be given extra time in all assessements/students should be given extra time in exams only/students should be given extra time in course-work, but not exams.